# Angular2 EventEmitter Not working and no errors

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to emit a simple event and I cant get it to work.

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'
import {MenuService} from "./menu.service";


    @Component({
        selector:'side-menu',
        templateUrl:'component.html',
    })

    export class SideMenuComponent {

        @Output() pinnedChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

        //Show and Hide the Detail Pane
        detailPanePinned = false;
        detailPaneVisible = false;

        pinMenuClick(){
            this.detailPanePinned = !this.detailPanePinned;
            this.detailPaneVisible = !this.detailPaneVisible;

            this.pinnedChange.emit({
                detailPanePinned: this.detailPanePinned
            })

        }

    }
```

Here is the HTML were I am trying to listen for it

```
<side-menu class="side-block pull-left">

</side-menu>
<design-pane (change)="onPinnedChange($event)"></design-pane>
<side-menu class="side-block pull-right">
</side-menu>
```

And here is the Component for the html above

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector:'builder-layout',
    templateUrl:'app/builder/layout/layout.component.html'
})

export class BuilderLayoutComponent {

    onPinnedChange($event){
        console.log($event)
    }
}
```

When I click `pinMenuClick` I dont get any error. It just doesnt hit my `onPinnedChange()`

I am using the Angular2 2.0.0 official

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that only the component that emits the event can listen to it, in your case, the side-menu. So you need to do something like this:

```
<side-menu (pinnedChange)="onPinnedChange($event)"></side-menu>
```